# Calculate Lebesgue measure of a subset of the irrationals in [0,1] that is uncountable, and it's inverse's measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been trying to find a Borel measurable set $B$ in [0,1] such that the intersection of $B$ with any open interval has non-zero Lebesgue measure (i.e. is dense in measure), and such that its complement $B^c$ is also dense in measure.

I have come up with the set $B=\{\mathbb{Q} \cup S\} $ where $S$ is the set containing any rational $r$ in the inteval in an infinite sum of the form

$$ r +\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{a_2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{a_3}{\sqrt{5}}+\cdots
$$

where $a_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and we do not need finitely  many non zero $a_i$.

This set contains non-algebraic numbers and therefore is at least a subset of the uncountable part of the irrationals. I believe it is indeed uncountable because for each rational number it can be combined with an infinite combination of the inverse square roots. In fact I'm fairly sure that the possible combinations for rational numbers in that interval with such square roots is the power set of the natural numbers.

My question is, how would I be able to calculate the measure of this set, or any intersection of this set with an open interval of [0,1]?

Comment: What do you mean by $B^c$? The most common use I know of for that notation is the complement of $B$. But $B \cap B^c = \emptyset$ for any $B$ by that definition.

Comment: Yes I do indeed mean the complement. Sorry I see the confusion in the wording now - I will edit it. I meant that the intersection of either B, or it's complement with any open interval has non-zero Lebesgue measure

Comment: That is clearer, but it now sounds like just one of $B$ and $B^c$ needs to be dense in measure (which is trivial). Surely you mean that both need to be dense in measure.

Comment: What proof do you have that $S$ contains transcendental numbers? Proving transcendentality is actually rather hard to do.  As for uncountability, if you dropped the requirement of only finitely many $0$s, it would be easy enough to prove it is uncountable just by the combinations where $a_i \ge 0$. But as is, proving that you cannot get same number from multiple sequences of the $a_i$ will be required, and that takes some work. I think there are much simpler approaches than this one.

Comment: One possibility would be to define $B$ as the set of $x$ in whose non-terminating binary expansion, eventually each stretch of $0$ bits between two $1$ bits is of even length. iT is almost trivial to show it is uncountable, and a construction somewhat similar to Cantor's should show that it is a Borel set. It is also easy to show it and its complement are dense. I am not sure whether its measure is non-zero, though.